# Symfony is injecting the wrong class as a dependency

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

As I am trying to load the `$userManager` parameter in the following class:

```
final class AclUserManager implements AdminAclUserManagerInterface
{
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    public function findUsers(): iterable
    {
        return $this->userManager->findUsers();
    }
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> App\Manager\AclUserManager::__construct(): Argument #1 ($userManager) must be of type App\Repository\UserManagerInterface, Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager given

This is the dependency injection segment from `services.yaml` :

```
    App\Manager\AclUserManager:
        arguments:
            - '@App\Repository\UserManagerInterface'
```

And this is the class definition:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface as UMI;

interface UserManagerInterface extends UMI
{
    public function findUsers(): ?array;

}
```

Comment: Can you update your question and show the use statement for UserManagerInterface?  It should be `use App\Repository\UserManagerInterface;`.  And then perhaps show the results of `bin/console debug:container UserManagerInterface`.